# Sign docker images with internal company's CA

Tags: docker, azure-aks

I'm new to Docker and Docker Trust. I'm bit confused about image signing and the role of Notary.

I've created a few docker images and pushed them to ACR (Azure Container Registry). Now the next part is to sign them. My question is can I use internal or 3rd party code-signing certificate to sign those images? If yes, any how-to pointers are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation for the key of the ACR Content Trust Keys is like it for the Docker Content Trust Keys. So you can use your existing internal certificate or 3rd party code-signing certificate for the ACR Content Trust Keys. You can follow the steps in [Signing Images with Docker Content Trust](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/content_trust/#signing-images-with-docker-content-trust).

What you need to do is that control the permission of the ACR. To push the sign image to ACR, it needs the permission **AcrImageSigner**, This is in addition to the AcrPush (or equivalent) role required for pushing images to the registry. And there is no difference in pull the image from ACR than usual. For more details, see [Grant image signing permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-content-trust#grant-image-signing-permissions).

Comment: I have tried to use code-signing cert but got error stating that cert file is not readable or writable. Did some search and found out that there is an open issue with Windows containers. So, then I tried custom public/private jet generated pair. But no success.

Comment: Everytime it fails with passphrase authentication. The a sample in the links uses the delegate keys signing option with image repository. In my case, image repository is not known upfront. E.g. abc.azurecr.io/team1/image:v1 and abc.azurecr.io/team2/image1:v1 and so on.

Comment: So, is the [Delegate image signing process](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/datacenter/dtr/2.2/guides/user/manage-images/sign-images/delegate-image-signing/) works with ACR?

Comment: @Sam As I test, you can load an existing certificate as the root password, and when you push an image to create a new repository, then you need to input a new password for the new repository. So you do not need to know image repository upfront.

Comment: So, what I'm doing wrong here:

`docker trust key generate tfssvc`
\n

`docker trust signer add --key tfssvc.pub tfssvc archacr01d.azurecr.io/team1/test`
\n

`docker push archacr01d.azurecr.io/team1/test/myimage:36`
\n

**Error:**
Enter passphrase for root key with ID 6bdaa1e:
Enter passphrase for new repository key with ID f8d867a:
Repeat passphrase for new repository key with ID f8d867a:
Passphrase incorrect. Please retry.

Comment: @Sam The repository `archacr01d.azurecr.io/team1/test` and `archacr01d.azurecr.io/team1/test/myimage:36` are two different. The root key is the same and does not change. You can just change the tag for echo repository.

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly. Delegation trust signing works at the image repository level. I need to update my statement to :

`docker trust signer add --key tfssvc.pub tfssvc archacr01d.azurecr.io/team1/test/myimage` 


I cannot add a delegator at namespace level (**test**) but only at image level (**myimage**)? Is this correct?

Comment: @Sam Yes, that's correct. For `archacr01d.azurecr.io/team1/test/myimage`, you just can add the key to the image level in `myimage`, not the namespace level `test`. Then you can change the tag like ../myimage:tag1, ../myimage:tag2 with the same key.

Comment: Got it. Let me try using a code-signing certificate.

Comment: `docker trust key load sample_private.key --name tfsdelegation01d`
throws **error**:

refusing to load key from sample_private.key: private key file sample_private.key must not be readable or writable by others

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1968. Hopefully, a new release have this fixed.

Comment: Once, they fix this and hopefully, then I'll able to use code-signing certificate for delegation trust. What will be my workflow looks like when the cert expires?

Comment: @Sam It's the same as you lose the key. Then you need to disable and enable it again in the ACR  and create the key.

Comment: I tried this command to remove existing set of keys `notaryclient.exe delegation remove testtemp.azurecr.io/team1/image1 targets/releases 870307s3221c3e0197004fcce0049ede79831cb1fc034a04ae72debca4e6345b --publish`
It prompts me for username and password where I supply the admin access keys from the azure registry. Then it prompts for repository key, where I supply the passphrase I used earlier. But it throws an error - **authorization access**. If I supply wrong credentials, it throws authentication failed. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Sam You need to disable the content trust on the ACR and enable it again first.

Comment: Ah ok. Got it. Thanks!